# Oxidation of Vitamin C

Tags: acid-base, redox

How is ascorbic acid oxidized into dehydroascorbic acid? What is the reduction reaction in this case? Where are the 2 hydrogen atoms going?
[image: Oxidation of Ascorbic Acid]

Comment: We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts, effort and attempts to understand underlaying principles. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you, and that the Q/A is beneficial for broad audience.
 
Basically any question with the wording your question has is considered homework; it needn't be literally one. It can be self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc.

Please [edit] in your full reasoning or thoughts on this. See [Homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448)

Otherwise, the question may get closed.‎

Comment: I think this question is too broad, it would be useful to see it narrowed down. Also, a little searching reveals some good hits explaining possible mechanisms. The underlying question (is there a duplicate?) seems very interesting (if, again, broad): what is the biochemical mechanism of oxidation of ascorbic acid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of oxidation in a classical sense for a minute or so. Oxidation is the addition of oxygen to a molecule or it can also mean the removal of hydrogen. If you carefully look at the structure of ascorbic acid, you will see that the two -$\ce{OH}$ groups are now converted into carbonyl groups. Those two hydrogens can be lost as a proton, $\ce{H+}$.